# Merge [reformatting] ← [reformat], [reformating]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Starting with the question counts, we have:

- **[reformat](/questions/tagged/reformat)**: 38 questions
- **[reformatting](/questions/tagged/reformatting)**: 13 questions
- **[reformating](/questions/tagged/reformating)**: 6 questions

[reformating](/questions/tagged/reformating) is clearly just a typo of [reformatting](/questions/tagged/reformatting), and tags are usually nouns rather than verbs, so I suggest:

- **[reformatting](/questions/tagged/reformatting)** ← [reformat](/questions/tagged/reformat), [reformating](/questions/tagged/reformating)

Comment: Also of note is the tag [tag:autoformatting], which may or may not be a good candidate to be merged as well.

Comment: **+1** for cool arrows. (I suggest, however, that [tag:reformatting] be made the primary - it just sounds better.)

Comment: @michaelb958: I agree. I swayed the other way because [tag:reformat] had more questions, but I guess it's a small number of questions either way.

Answer (score 6):

I manually burninated [reformating](/questions/tagged/reformating) (while fixing the other issues in the posts, of course).

[image]

I suggest going the other way though, [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) ← [format](/questions/tagged/format). Tags are mainly nouns; most of our tags are like that (for example, [writing](/questions/tagged/writing) (ugh that's also a terrible tag), [debugging](/questions/tagged/debugging), [sorting](/questions/tagged/sorting), [parsing](/questions/tagged/parsing), etc).

Comment: I agree that making [tag:reformatting] the master would be better; I swayed the other way since it had more questions, but I guess it's a small number either way. I've edited my question to reflect that.